# Run simple timer

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, f#, timer

I'm trying to run simple timer on project startup:

```
type NJHomeViewModel(config : Config) as X  =  
    inherit ViewModelBase()

    do
        (X.Timer : Timer).Elapsed.Add(fun args -> X.OnTimedEvent(args))
        (X.Timer : Timer).Interval  <- 3000.0
        (X.Timer : Timer).Enabled   <- true
        (X.Timer : Timer).Start()

    member X.Timer = new Timer()

    member X.OnTimedEvent args = X.Change()
```

So I want each 3 seconds run X.Change() function, it doesn't work this way, even when I added it to button nothing is changed.

```
member X.Next =
    new RelayCommand((fun canExecute -> true),
        (fun action -> 
            (X.Timer : Timer).Elapsed.Add(fun args -> X.OnTimedEvent(args))
            (X.Timer : Timer).Interval  <- 3000.0
            (X.Timer : Timer).Enabled   <- true
            (X.Timer : Timer).Start() ))
```

What is correct way to start my timer with a "Tick" action ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`member X.Timer = new Timer()` This creates a property with a getter and when you access this property every time a new Timer is created.

To avoid this you can use a let binding as:

```
type NJHomeViewModel(config : Config) as X  =  
    inherit ViewModelBase()


    let timer = new Timer()
    do 
      timer.Elapsed.Add(fun args -> X.OnTimedEvent(args))
      timer.Interval  <- 3000.0
      timer.Enabled   <- true
      timer.Start()

    member X.Timer = timer

    member X.OnTimedEvent args = X.Change()
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider an async loop in preference to using a timer; see e.g.

http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/f-async-on-the-client-side/

which has an example like

```
async {
    while true do
        do! Async.Sleep 1000
        textBox.Text <- System.DateTime.Now.ToString()
} |> Async.StartImmediate
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the server-based [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ekh5acz.aspx) which exposes an Elapsed event. There are other Timers available to you (e.g. the [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx#Y1700) where you can provide a callback method or the [Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) where you can subscribe to the Tick event) so you need to pick the one most appropriate for your application and your use case. MSDN has an article about when to use which .NET Timer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

For the timer you are using, the Elapsed event will only run once if in a certain state. So that could be your problem. From MSDN

> If Enabled is set to true and AutoReset is set to false, the Timer
>   raises the Elapsed event only once, the first time the interval
>   elapses.

The Threading timer would look something like

```
new Timer((fun _ -> YourMethod), null, 1000, 1000)
```

The Windows.Forms.Timer would look something like

```
formsTimer.Tick.Add( fun _ -> YourMethod())
```

In WPF you also have the [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx#S5) available to you (more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx)). in F# this would look something like

```
let tmr = new DispatcherTimer(Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
tmr.Tick.Add( fun _ -> YourMethod())
tmr.Start()
```

There is a concise comparison of Forms.Timer and DispatcherTimer in [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111645/comparing-timer-with-dispatchertimer) that might help you choose the right one for your app.