# WinAPI SetTimer() conflicts with WPF threading model

Tags: wpf, winapi

It seems WinAPI SetTimer() conflicts with WPF threading model.
If you call SetTimer() in WPF main thread, it may cause the timer not to fire properly.
HWND for SetTimer() is null.
Is that conflict true?

Comment: Try using the WPF specific DispatcherTimer instead.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111645/comparing-timer-with-dispatchertimer.

Comment: I don't know absolutely, but I do know that WPF does not use the Win32 API like Winforms does.  I would recommend reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx#hwnds

Comment: I cannot control what timer to use because SetTimer() is called by a proprietary dll.