# WCF call blocks UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

I've setup a DispatcherTimer that calls a WCF service on each tick event. After the service is called I'd like to update the UI without blocking it, so I've marked both the event handler for the timer and the method that makes the WCF call as async and included await commands in the relevant places (see code below). However, the UI is still getting blocked. Any ideas?

```
    static async void connectivityTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person person = await ServiceClient.GetPersonAsync();

        lblText.Text = person.Name;
    }

    public static async Task<Person> GetPersonAsync()
    {
         Service.Client client = new Service.Client();

         Task<string> serviceResult = client.GetPersonAsync();

         string contentResults = await serviceResult;

         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonContainer));

         using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(contentResults))
         {
                return ((PersonContainer)serializer.Deserialize(reader)).Person;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment John. I have exception handling code in that method, i removed it form my post for simplicity.

Comment: Done, try/catch blocks removed

Comment: Thanks. In general, keep irrelevant code out of the question - we tend to think that whatever is in the question is relevant.

Comment: You should use System.Timer instead of DispatcherTimer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111645/comparing-timer-with-dispatchertimer

Comment: How often is the Tick event fired?

Comment: @Matt Why would he do that? He updates a label in the Tick event.

Comment: It's configurable, but right now it fires every 30 seconds

Comment: How about `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (()=> lblText.Text = person.Name))`?