# Dispatch timer won't work

Tags: c#, uwp, dispatchertimer

I'm trying to figure out how a dispatch timer works so I can implement it into my program, I followed the exact instructions on a website and looked for answers on stack overflow. People said their problem was fixed but I have very similar code and it wont work...

The error is:

> No overload for "timer_Tick" matches delegate "EventHandler<object>"

What can i do?

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(EventArgs e)
{
    TimeRefresh();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fix the event handler signature. It's missing the sender and the type of the second parameter is just `object`. *(See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.tick).)*

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    TimeRefresh();
}
```

You also need to add a `using Windows.UI.Xaml;` to the top of your class, or instantiate the timer using the full namespace:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer timer = new Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer();
```

---

If anyone stumbles on this and is using WPF, it has it own [DispatchTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.tick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Make sure you're referencing "WindowsBase" *(should be there by default)*. The signature is slightly different.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeRefresh();
}
```

The namespace it lives in is different too. Either add `using System.Windows.Threading;` to the top, or qualify with the full namespace:

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer
    = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
```

---

If you're using WinForms, you want to use a different timer. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1111699/301857) for the difference between the WinForms Timer and the WPF DispatchTimer.

Comment: I use DispatchTimer, But when i use `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` It says `The type or namespace name 'Threading' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Must be missing `System.Windows.Threading` assembly reference

Comment: @Victor , How do I add that?

Comment: Maybe I am missing "WindowsBase.dll" I haven't added a reference before, How can try see if its missing and add it if it is?

Comment: No, All i see is system.windows

Comment: what about including `timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);` line

Comment: No, Its definitely a WPF application. I know the difference between WinForms and WPF @un-lucky

Comment: Do I right click on references and click add reference? I tried searching for windowsbase but nothing came up

Comment: "No framework assemblies were found on this machine"

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the source of event.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    TimeRefresh();
}
```

And the event registration should be like the following:

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp) you can read more about events and event handlers